# Probability of seeing each face except one in $n$ throws of a die with 4 faces

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, dice, coupon-collector

Imagine that we throw a die with 4 faces $n$ times. The faces have probabilities of $(0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3)$ of showing up.

**What is the probability that we see all faces except a specific, pre-determined face $i$ (say $i = 1$) in $n$ throws?**

PS: This isn't homework but a puzzle that came across that I couldn't solve analytically. Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $k_i$?    Is the missing face specified in advance?

Comment: @lulu I added more detail. But yes, we pre-determine a specific face $i$ and ask what's the probability that we don't see that face in $n$ throws. Please ask if anything is still unclear.

Comment: You can't work this out without having the probability of the face coming up or such

Comment: @Sergio I have edited the question to make it more concrete. Is it solvable now?

Comment: The difficulty is that it is quite hard to ensure that all the other faces come up. Ordinarily, one can fall back on symmetry, but there is no symmetry here.  Inclusion Exclusion will give you a (very messy) way to do it.  But the number of cases you need to consider grows rather quickly.

Comment: @lulu Hm yes, I suspected that the messy way of inclusion exclusion is the way to go. I hoped that there is a nice, more elegant way. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Note:  I had not noticed that you revised the problem to only consider $4$ faces.  In that case, the  Inclusion-Exclusion computation is perfectly manageable (though still a bit messy).  You can consider simulation as an easy way to approximate the thing.  Though even simulation will tend to break down if there are lots of faces or if some of the faces have very low probabilities.

Comment: You already have a good answer I see, you can use any numbers you want as you edited your post but as I mentioned it is impossible to get a final answer without having the probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any formula for this is going to be messy, but I can explain to you how to do the problem.  I'm assuming that the forbidden face is specified in advance.  If you mean to say all but one (unspecified) face, do the problem for each specific face and add up the answers.

The probability that face $i$ doesn't show up on a single toss is $(1-p_i)$ and the probability that it doesn't show up in $n$ tosses is $(1-p_i)^n.$  However, this includes cases where some other face doesn't show up either, so we must subtract $$\sum_{j\neq i}(1-p_i-p_j)^n$$  where it is understood that $1\leq j\leq k$.  (Sorry, I don't know how to get two lines in the subscript in MathJax.)  This isn't the end of the story.  Suppose in some sequence of tosses that doesn't include $i$ neither $j$ nor $m$ has shown up.  We've subtracted the probability of this sequence twice, and we only want to subtract once so we need to add it back.  That is, we must add $$\sum(1-p_i-p_j-p_m)^n$$ where the sum is over all $2$-element sets $\{j,m\}$, with $1\leq j,m\leq k$ with $i\neq j,\ i\neq m$.

Now of course, we have to consider sequences where $3$ faces other than $i$ don't show up.  We continue as above, alternately, adding and subtracting, by applying the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: With a couple of definitions one can express this as a quite nice formula.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't win any beauty contests, but you could imagine a transition matrix between the sixteen possible states of combinations of faces that would come up.  For instance, if you imagined the problem with flipping a coin with a $\frac13$ probability of heads and a $\frac23$ probability of tails, your matrix would look like this:

$$
    M=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac13 & \frac13 & 0& 0 \\
    \frac23 & 0 & \frac23 & 0 \\
    0 & \frac23 & \frac13 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

where the first column represents not seeing any results, the second representing heads only, the third tails only, and the fourth both heads and tails.  Then you could just calculate $$M^n\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ for any $n$ that interestsed you and read off the probability for the individual final state that interested you.  Your problem would invove a $16\times16$ matrix, but it wouldn't be hard to create it and load it into Mathematica or wherever to churn out the probability you wanted.